# If I build a .NET application in mono on Linux, is the compiled executable directly portable to Windows 7?

Tags: f#, mono

I have mono installed on my Linux laptop, and I started learning how to write F# programs with basic Windows.Forms interfaces.

Will the *.exe files I compile on Linux using fsc run directly on Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the answer is Yes, in that '.NET' is '.NET' is '.NET' -- there may be a few features in the latest Windows CLR that do not exist in mono, but not the other way around.

Comment: "'.NET' is '.NET' is '.NET'" and "there may be a few features in the latest Windows CLR that do not exist in mono". Contradicting yourself in your own answer?

Comment: thanks Davie. what i meant was simply if it works in mono then it works on windows. they're not making they're own runtime they're mimicking.

Comment: provide your own answer Davey. don't heckle

Comment: The answer is fine (I didn't/wouldn't downvote). I agree that that if it works on Mono then it will probably work on the Windows CLR. The answer just seemed to contradict itself a little (author may choose to clarify).

Comment: There are some unique features in Mono which are not directly available in Microsoft .NET - e.g., SIMD extensions. And, of course, P/Invokes are unlikely to be portable.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this recently, but two years ago I built simple Windows Forms applications in Mono compiled on a Debian Linux Itanium system and these applications ran perfectly on Windows Vista running on an AMD Athlon64.

So I would say the answer is Yes.